# What are the correct access rights for the com.apple.dock.plist file on OS X?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, osx-mountain-lion

After having some problems removing items from the dock on OS X (Mountain Lion) today, I found out that if I reset the access rights on a particular file to give everyone all rights, it worked.

This is the command I used:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

However, I don't particularly like those rights.

When I executed this command before changing to everything:

```
ls -la ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

It said:

```
-rw-------
```

Can anyone tell me what the correct access rights should be?

Comment: The original permissions are the default.

Comment: Make sure your numeric uid (use id -u to check it) matches the uid that owns the file (ls -n).

Comment: Never used it, but maybe [Disk Utility's Fix Permissions](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452)

Answer (score 0):

The default/correct permission should be as follow

```
-rw-------   1 <username>  staff   4.3K Jan 15 09:42 com.apple.dock.plist
```

If the user is `john`, the full path will be

```
Users/john/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

The default permission should be as follow

```
-rw-------   1 john  staff   4.3K Jan 15 09:42 com.apple.dock.plist
```

Common cause of the permission become wrong is when the user folder is moved/migrated from another OS X box or home folder being assigned to another account due to various reason.

To fix it, instead of changing permission, assign it to the correct user

```
chown <username> com.apple.dock.plist
```

If you want to reset ownership for the whole user directory

```
cd /Users
chown -R john john
```

The first `john` is username, the second `john` is directory name.